# How to embedding the clipping values from illustrator image

Tags: clip, illustrator, cutwin

[image]Here I using cutwin package for clipping images wrap around text and the values of each and every line need manual intervention. I have an illustrator clipping values of the image. Is there any possible way to embedding the values into LaTeX.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cutwin,wrapfig,graphicx}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample chapter}


In this topic, we have learned about the sharp rise and fall of one of the world's greatest empires, as well as the leaders at the heart of it. The Yuan dynasty was full of contrasts, from its violent conquests to its tolerance of different beliefs and promotion of multicultural city centres. We also considered the different experiences of those living within the Mongols realm during their century-long rule.\clearpage


\renewcommand*{\putstuffinpic}{%
\put(0,-50){\makebox(0,0){\includegraphics[height=94pt]{c01uf027.pdf}}}}

%\opencutright
\begin{shapedcutout}{3}{9}{%
165pt,165pt,%x
140pt,150pt,%
110pt,105pt,%
100pt,105pt,%
135pt,110pt,%
133pt,130pt,%
128pt,155pt,%
115pt,160pt,
110pt,170pt}
In this topic, we have learned about the sharp rise and fall of one of the world's greatest empires, as well as the leaders at the heart of it. The Yuan dynasty was full of contrasts, from its violent conquests to its tolerance of different beliefs and promotion of multicultural city centres. We also considered the different experiences of those living within the Mongols realm during their century-long rule.
In this topic, we have learned about the sharp rise and fall of one of the world's greatest empires, as well as the leaders at the heart of it. The Yuan dynasty was full of contrasts, from its violent conquests to its tolerance of different beliefs and promotion of multicultural city centres. We also considered the different experiences of those living within the Mongols realm during their century-long rule.
In this topic, we have learned about the sharp rise and fall of one of the world's greatest empires, as well as the leaders at the heart of it. The Yuan dynasty was full of contrasts, from its violent conquests to its tolerance of different beliefs and promotion of multicultural city centres. We also considered the different experiences of those living within the Mongols realm during their century-long rule.
\end{shapedcutout}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the format of the 'illustrator clipping values'?

Comment: Here I mentioned the adobe illustrator (a vector graphics editor). A clipping value is a shape called a clipping path that masks any object below it, so only what's inside of the clipping path is visible.

Comment: I am not familiar with the editor. Please could you provide an example of its output?

Comment: It may be possible to construct a macro of shapedcutout parameters using  something like csvsimple or plain TeX file IO.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what is csvsimple and also suggest, I have a image values in art file like EPS, JPEG, etc. How could I get the values of images and import into LaTeX. Here I attached image which for your reference

Comment: That isn't really LaTeX's strong suit.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for your valuable response.